# pipenv under pyenv fails to upgrade its instance under pyenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-venv, virtualenvwrapper, pyenv

After brew upgrading pipenv in MacOS

```
==> Installing pipenv
==> Pouring pipenv--2022.1.8.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2022.1.8: 1,767 files, 28MB
```

I see that the version of `pipenv` under `pyenv` is NOT updated:

```
> which pipenv
pipenv is /Users/me/.pyenv/shims/pipenv
pipenv is /usr/local/bin/pipenv
```

UPDATED:

```
> /usr/local/bin/pipenv --version
pipenv, version 2022.1.8
```

NOT UPDATED:

```
> /Users/me/.pyenv/shims/pipenv --version
pipenv, version 2020.11.15
```

How do I make sure the version under `pyenv` gets upgraded also?

Answer (score 0):

You need to uninstall `pipenv` with brew

```sh
brew uninstall pipenv
```

You can install `pipenv` under `pyenv` python version

```sh
pyenv global <PYTHON_VERSION>
pip install pipenv
```

or install `pipenv` under a virtualenv

```sh
pyenv activate <PYENV_VIRTUALENV>
pip install pipenv
```